# Chrome Loads Slow on Large Selects

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome

In my HTML page I have a `<select>` element with thousands of `<option>` elements, which are generated in the JSP.

When the page loads in IE and in Firefox it loads pretty quickly, however when loading in Chrome the load time is significantly longer. (It can take up to a minute.) I replaced the `<select>` and `<option>` elements with `<div>` tags, and surprisingly, it loaded much quicker (within a few seconds).

After inspecting the timeline in dev tools I noticed that when I use the options, the 'loading' time is very long - specifically the `parseHTML` (seen in the Event Log). However, when I replaced the select with divs the loading time was just a few milliseconds. The rendering was actually longer (as said before it wasn't very long) than the loading, and interestingly - it was longer than the rendering for options.

I would love to understand the following:

- What is the exact difference between rendering and loading - specifically `parseHTML`?
- Why is it that divs act differently than options?
- Most importantly, how can i use the select without using select2 or other dynamically loading select boxes, and still get good loading time?

**Update**

After some playing around i discovered how to fix it but i was left more perplexed than before.

I created two JSPs ,one with the size attribute specified, and one without.

```
    <select size="10">
    <%                  
    for(int i = 0; i< 60000; i++){ %>
        <option value="<%=i%>"><%=i%></option>
    <%} %></select>
```

The one with the size attribute took about 2 minutes, while the one without took only 10 seconds!!!

Here too, I inspected the Timeline, and - as before - the one with the size had the 'loading' event (`parseHTML`) taking up 80% of the loading time and took 99 seconds long, while the one without the size had the 'loading' event taking only 3% of loading time, (465 ms) with the 'rendering' taking up 75% of the loading time (7.8 seconds).

It's possibly a bug in chrome, however i would love to understand what's going on here.

P.S. I know its not a good idea to use scriplets in JSP, this is just for testing purposes, also this issue is not connected to JSP in particular, but rather a general HTML issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Adding the options dynamically with the onclick method resolved it. The page loads quickly and the options are added only when user clicks it.

```
<SELECT name='xyz' onclick="addOptions(this) " >
<option value='abcd' SELECTED > text </option>  
<!--  so that atleast one option is visible. -->    
</SELECT>

function addOptions ( element )
{
    /// some loop 
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = carrierCodeTypeMemberCodes[carOptions] ;
        option.text = carrierCodeTypeMemberValues[carOptions];
        element.add( option );
    }
    element.click();  //// This is required to refresh the select box. 
}
```